# adding gridlock to .draggable without redefining it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When a button is clicked, i wanted to turn on/off gridlock.  The thing is that i dont want to redefine it each time like i currently have.

Right now i end up doing extensive code behind the design of .draggable() and its attributes.

When i click the button to turn on gridlock, it more or less just does

```
 $("div.draggable").draggable({
     "option": "grid", [20,20]
 });
```

and when it is removed, i would say:

```
$("div.draggable").draggable({
   "option", "grid", false
});
```

in the codebehind, which overrides everything in place.

Is there a way to take say the current running draggable and extend it to more or less override the gridlock functionality?

I could store each elements contents in a function and just recall everything, but i feel that is silly when you could take something running and then modify it while it is running without a new definition.

Thoughts?  IdeaS?

**edit:  My goal is  to allow it so that all the current inplace functionality will remain, and then just modify the grid controls.**

*In my mind, i was thinking that giving it this ability is a redefinition, and not just an application of a process.  Maybe it isnt reapplying stuff, but instead modifying it?*

Answer (score 0):

My issue was moreso in the idea that the lines were not being executed.  When it did hit it, everything started working again.